# array item assigning in sorting functions of c++

Tags: c++

its not correctly assigning items in an array during the sorting function of selection sort in c++.what is the correct way?

```
int a[] = { 22, 91, 35, 78, 10, 8, 75, 99, 1, 67 };
int arr_len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

for(int index = 0; index < arr_len - 1; index++)
{
    for(int n = index + 1; n < arr_len; n++)
    {
        if(a[index] > a[n])
        {
            a[index] = a[n];
            a[n] = a[index];
        }
    }
}
```

the result of my program gave me like this: 
Array in sorted order: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 67

Comment: `a=b` followed by `b=a` will make both `a,b = b`

Comment: Two swap two elements use a "temp" value. `temp=a; a=b; b= temp;`

Comment: or directly `std::swap`.

Comment: Unrelated: If t you're compiling to a recent standard, `std::size` can be used to replace `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you want to swap `a` and `b`. Let's say that the values are:

```
a = x
b = y
```

The first step of your attempt was to assign `a = b`. After such operation, the situation would be:

```
a = y
b = y
```

How could you at this point assign `x` to `b`? Think about it.

You can't. The original value of `a` has been lost. So, clearly this first step leads to a dead end.

The solution: Introduce a new variable, assign `a` onto that variable, assign `b` onto `a`, and finally assign the new variable onto `b`.

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```